# Customize add to cart message in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, notice

I would like to change the '"[product name]" has been added to your basket' prompt to say 'x item(s) has/have been added to your basket'.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880460/woocommerce-how-to-edit-the-added-to-cart-message) explains how to edit the add to cart message, but I cannot find any information about the variables which can be used.

How can I show the number of products added rather than the name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3, the filter hook `wc_add_to_cart_message` is obsolete and it's now replaced by [`wc_add_to_cart_message_html`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_add_to_cart_message.html#125)…

The function usable variables arguments are two:

- `$message` that is the outputed string message
- `$products` that is an indexed array containing the product Id / quantity pairs *(key / value)*.

To change the default ***"`{qty}` x `{product-name}` has(ve) been added to your cart"*** message to:

> ***`{qty}` item(s) has/have been added to your basket.***

You will use the following:

```
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'custom_add_to_cart_message_html', 10, 2 );
function custom_add_to_cart_message_html( $message, $products ) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ( $products as $product_id => $qty ) {
        $count += $qty;
    }
    // The custom message is just below
    $added_text = sprintf( _n("%s item has %s", "%s items have %s", $count, "woocommerce" ),
        $count, __("been added to your basket.", "woocommerce") );

    // Output success messages
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add' ) ) {
        $return_to = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_continue_shopping_redirect', wc_get_raw_referer() ? wp_validate_redirect( wc_get_raw_referer(), false ) : wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) );
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( $return_to ), esc_html__( 'Continue shopping', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    } else {
        $message   = sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s', esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ), esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $added_text ) );
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The code is working perfectly. but
instead of showing quantity, if someone wants the product's title to be shown and the view cart button shows below it, then?